# How efficient/fast is Python's 'in'? (Time Complexity wise)

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity, operator-keyword

In Python, what is the efficiency of the `in` keyword, such as in:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
if 4 in a:
  ...
```

Comment: How can a keyword be efficient?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It depends on the right hand [operand](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in):

> The operators `in` and `not in` test for collection membership. [...] The collection membership test has traditionally been bound to sequences; an object is a member of a collection if the collection is a sequence and contains an element equal to that object. However, it make sense for many other object types to support membership tests without being a sequence. In particular, dictionaries (for keys) and sets support membership testing.

Classes can implement the [special method `__contains__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) to override the default behavior (iterating over the sequence) and thus can provide a more (or less) efficient way to test membership than comparing every element of the container.

> The membership test operators (`in` and `not in`) are normally implemented as an iteration through a sequence. However, container objects can supply the following special method with a more efficient implementation, which also does not require the object be a sequence.

---

Since you have a list in your example, it is iterated over and each element is compared until a match is found or the list is exhausted. The time complexity is usually `O(n)`.

Comment: I suppose it will be the same for strings?

Comment: `The collection membership test has traditionally been bound to sequences;` Strings in python are sequences.

Comment: @Felix Kling If list is converted to a set before checking if element is part of it, will it be faster compared to checking directly in list?

Comment: @KocT9H: Depends on how often you do the check. If it's only once, then there will be no difference since, I assume, converting the the list to a set is also `O(n)`.

Answer (score 56):

The complexity for lists is:

```
O(n)
```

For sets it is:

```
O(1)
```

http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: In general, but Felix Kling's answer is best. Someone could implement a `MembershipList` class which has a base list and also a membership set instance variable, and override `__contains__` to check the set for O(1) time.

Comment: what about dictionaries @eduardo :)

Comment: [Implementation, where oneverify that it does, indeed, involve iterating](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L441-L454)