# search a word in a file and print the line number where that word occurs in python

Tags: python, line-numbers

How do you get your function to find the lines in the text file where the word occurs and print the corresponding line numbers?

I had to open a text file with the paragraph and then am supposed to search the paragraph for certain words and then print the specific line numbers for the words.

Here is what I have so far.

```
def index (filepath, keywords):

    file = open(filepath)
    files_lines = [line for line in file]
    counter = 0
    for line in files_lines:
        counter += 1
        if line.find(keywords) >= 0:
            print(keywords, counter)
    counter = 0
```

This is how the output should be

```
    >>index('file.txt',['network', 'device', 'local'])

network    9

device     4

local      11
```

Note: Network, Device and local are the words im trying to search within the file and 9, 4, 11 are the line numbers on which these words occur.

I am getting an error that cannot convert list into str implicitly. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How does the question define a word?

Comment: What if a word occurs on multiple lines? What if multiple keywords appear on the same line?

Answer (score 2):

```
if line.find(keywords) >= 0:
```

is wrong. you need to find out if any element of `keywords` is contained in `line`. like this

```
if any(line.find(kw) > 0 for kw in keywords):
```

BTW, the lines

```
files_lines = [line for line in file]
counter = 0
```

are not very pythonic, better like this:

```
def index (filepath, keywords):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for counter, line in enumerate(f, start = 1):
            if line.find(keywords) >= 0:
               print(keywords, counter)
```

**Acknowledgement**: Thanks to Lukas Graf for showing me it's necessary to set the `start` parameter in `enumerate`

Comment: That won't result in the OP's example output though, and line numbers will be off by one.

Comment: You should use 'in' instead of '.find' - it's faster and 'more pythonic': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437798/find-vs-in-operation-in-string-python

Answer (score 1):

You get the error

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

because with `line.find(keywords)` you're passing a list (`keywords`) to `find()` which expects a string.

You need to search for each keyword individually instead using a loop:

```
def index(filepath, keywords):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
            matches = [k for k in keywords if k in line]
            if matches:
                result = "{:<15} {}".format(','.join(matches), lineno)
                print(result)


index('file.txt', ['network', 'device', 'local'])
```

Here I also used [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to simplify line counting and [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to make the output [aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684368/how-to-left-align-a-fixed-width-string) like in your example. The expression `matches = [k for k in keywords if k in line]` is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that builds a list of all the keywords that are a substring of `line`.

Example output:

```
network,device  1
network         2
device          3
local           4
device,local    5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error `cannot convert list to str implicity` it means that you have written an argument which will work for a string, but not for a list.

**One way to fix this error:**

```
variable = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

variable = str(variable)
# NOW ARGUMENT
variable = list(variable) # change it back
```

I'm not sure if this helps you, but others have answered your question and mine was only input for extra knowledge's sake, if you didn't already know this know you do!